# Multiprocessing with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

When I apply Multiprocessing in a Pandas data frame with a rolling function it returns NaN. Please find the code below.

```
import multiprocessing
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def _apply_df(args):
    df, func, num, kwargs = args
    return num, df.apply(func, **kwargs)

def apply_by_multiprocessing(df,func,**kwargs):
  workers=kwargs.pop('workers')
  pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=workers)
  result = pool.map(_apply_df, [(d, func, i, kwargs) for i,d in enumerate(np.array_split(df, workers))])  
  pool.close()
  result=sorted(result,key=lambda x:x[0])
  return pd.concat([i[1] for i in result])

def square(df):
     df1 = df.rolling(10).mean()
     return df1

df_total_2 =  pd.DataFrame({'a':range(1000), 'b':range(1000)})
apply_by_multiprocessing(df_total_2, square, axis=1, workers=2)
```

However, if I change the "square" function to:

```
def square(x):
    df1 = x*x
    return df1
```

It produces the correct answer.
I guess the function "square" is being applied row wise and not column wise.

I also tried using the "lambda" function, as:

```
def square(df):
     df1 = (df.apply(lambda x: x.mean())) # do a rolling mean
     return df1
```

returning the following error:

```
apply_by_multiprocessing(df_total, square, axis=1, workers=4)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-40-663c5a81f7cd>", line 1, in <module>
    apply_by_multiprocessing(df_total, square, axis=1, workers=4)

  File "<ipython-input-1-fd95c66a9065>", line 13, in    apply_by_multiprocessing
    result = pool.map(_apply_df, [(d, func, i, kwargs) for i,d in   enumerate(np.array_split(df, workers))])

  File   "/Users/caiopisciotto/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py",   line 253, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()

  File "/Users/caiopisciotto/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 572, in get
raise self._value

AttributeError: ("'float' object has no attribute 'mean'", u'occurred  at index 0')
```

Can someone point out what I am doing wrong or any workaround, please?

Thank you,

Comment: Might be helpful to look into [`dask`](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe.html)

Comment: @BradSolomon thank you, I will look.

Answer (score 0):

For what it seems, this is not a problem related to multiprocessing itself but rather the specification of `axis=1` which will process the rolling average on the [row axis](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/frame.py#L5543) instead of the column one (as so you desire).

Try this instead:

```
apply_by_multiprocessing(df_total_2, square, axis=0, workers=2)
```

It also looks like you want results squared, so you can adapt your `square` function to:

```
def square(df):
     df1 = df.rolling(10).mean() ** 2
     return df1
```

Notice the function that worked for you:

```
def square(x):
    df1 = x*x
    return df1
```

is not quite generating results you desire (as it does not consider the rolling average).

Comment: thx, I tried your suggestion with "rolling(3)"
    apply_by_multiprocessing(df_total_2, square, axis=0, workers=4)
    Out[76]: 
     a    b
0  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN
2  1.0  1.0
3  NaN  NaN
4  NaN  NaN
5  4.0  4.0
6  NaN  NaN
7  NaN  NaN
8  NaN  NaN
9  NaN  NaN
Any idea, thank you?

Comment: that's weird...just tested it here and it's working normally for me. Maybe there's a code difference somewhere?